# How to backup mongodb from windows machine to mac os?

Tags: windows, macos, mongodb, backup, restore

I am new to mongodb. I have a mongodb database of 2gb size in windows machine. I want to backup and restore it to my mac os. I tried copying and pasting the /data/db folders from windows to my mac machine. But it didn't work. The database is not showing up in mac on doing this. I guess I missing something majorly. Can someone assist me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting mongoDB to a JSON file using command :

mongoexport --host "localhost:27017" --collection coll_Name --db db_Name --any_file_Name "path to get the any_file_Name.json file"

And to import this json in mac type command :

mongoimport --db db_Name --collection coll_Name --file "any_file_Name.json path"

Answer (score 0):

You should use [back and restore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/back-up-and-restore-with-mongodb-tools/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I looked at it. When i tried mongodump it didn't work. Not sure which is the right one to use.

Comment: hey..I got it fixed. I sued mongodb import and export using json files. I was able to export my database to json file and restore it from it. It helped! Thanks much!